# Is Wukong a viable champion?

Tags: league-of-legends

He has a lot of good options, including:

- AD burst damage.
- Great initiation with his E - **Nimbus Strike** - skill.
- He has few seconds of stealth with W - **Decoy** - great escape or initiation mechanism.
- Movable AOE CC ultimate with his **Cyclone**.

He is good as a tank with Frozen Mallet or as a AD Burster with Black Cleaver.

He seems to have a lot of upsides, but I never see him in competitive play. Why is he used so infrequently at the highest level?

Comment: This is not primarily opinion based, as a League player I can attest that this can be answered factually and with legitimate reasoning.

Comment: I would say it's opinion and time sensitive, if you look at the related questions, 'Why isn't so and so seen?', they are seen commonly now(Cho,tryn,grag,kass). I'm not sure if this question will be helpful in a month or even after this next week as maybe everyone will choose wukong this week. In short, he's not the fotm

Comment: @Brian with your idea in mind please put on hold other such questions like this http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58026/why-is-kassadin-not-played-in-tournaments? or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58524/why-is-karma-not-played-as-much-as-other-supports? or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93885/why-is-tryndamere-not-seen-in-competitive-play?

Comment: Not enough rep to put on hold but pls see http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7518/18146 someone opened a meta discussion about it

Comment: @Brian and top 1 answer "Questions about champion viability are clearly on topic" and later it is  "Why isn't Wukong used in competitive play?" to "Is Wukong a viable champion?" so maybe next time think about editing question not closing it.

Comment: @iber That meta discussion came about as a result of this question being closed.  Putting a question on hold while its on-topicness is discussed is exactly the way the system is meant to work.

Comment: I feel that if I post an answer it would be too biased as I play him often. But, anyways, I feel with his passive armor&mr per enemy champ, he can really excel in late-game and teamfighting along with his cc-centered ultimate, regardless of wether he does bad in lane or not. He can also play like an assassin and pick off any stragglers/squishy champs with Nimbus Strike (E), and shred tank's armor as well with Crushing Blow (Q). His W also allows for unique and interesting plays/escapes if used right. Overall, I feel like Wukong is a rather versatile champ and quite viable.

Comment: Wukong not being picked in competitive play doesn't mean he's bad for you. As a matter of fact, he has a very high win ratio in solo queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Wukong and find playing him in casual play to be both fun and effective but I can see where he may not translate well to higher level play.

His strengths include burst damage and a strong team ult. The knockup and damage are both significant.

Wukong is lacking in the laning phase against most currently popular top lane champions. He does not have any form of crowd control until he gets his ult, he doesn't really have any range and as a result of these two things, he can get zoned. He also can't really harass very well against opponents that understand how Wukong works.

The standard Wukong combo is to Nimbus Strike in, Crushing Blow and use Decoy to prevent retaliation. That puts all three of his abilities on cooldown and him mostly within range of the enemy at the end of the Decoy invisibility. If the enemy recognizes this and proceed to walk toward where you will come out of Decoy, your invisibility will end and they will have just begun their combo which will likely include a slow/stun/root, ignite and whatever else they want to throw at you.

Now there is some trickery to do with Decoy like using the stop command to make it look like you used decoy. This tactic becomes less effective as the opponent's skill level increases.

I don't think that Wukong is weak but he just doesn't quite fit in the current meta or there are just stronger options since he doens't really hard-counter any champions.

Comment: Not to mention, Wukong has relatively low sustainability compared to a lot of popular solo tops and his passive doesn't really come into play in a solo lane.

Answer (score 2):

I would say given the right team composition/lane strategy any champ could be played competitively. However, Wukong has some things currently working against him.

Wukong is a top lane champion in the current meta. Top lanes currently run solo and at times he will be fighting 2v1 (opposing top lane and jungle). Wukong does not perform well 2v1 because he is a non-tanky melee champ.

Also, one of wukong common counters is Lee Sin, who happens to be a  fairly common pick in competitive play.